# Wordpress Custom Post Types Problem

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

Been trying to add custom post type which was successful the problem i am having is with adding metabox and inputs for these post types here is the code i have:
functions.php
    add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

```
    function admin_init(){
        add_meta_box("deal-meta", "Deal Options", "deal_options", "deal", "side", "low");
    }

    function deal_options(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $price = $custom["price"][0];
        $discount = $custom["discount"][0];
        $market_value = $custom["market_value"][0];
        $start_date = $custom["start_date"][0];
        $end_date = $custom["end_date"][0];
        $highlights = $custom["highlights"][0];
        $fine_print = $custom["fine_print"][0];
        $quick_description = $custom["quick_description"][0];
        ?>
        <label>Price:</label>
        <input name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />

        <label>Discount:</label>
        <input name="discount" value="<?php echo $discount; ?>" />

        <label>Market Value:</label>
        <input name="market_value" value="<?php echo $market_value; ?>" />

        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <input name="start_date" value="<?php echo $start_date; ?>" />

        <label>End Date:</label>
        <input name="end_date" value="<?php echo $end_date; ?>" />

        <label>Highlights:</label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="highlights"><?php echo $highlights; ?></textarea>

        <label>Fine Print:</label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="fine_print"><?php echo $fine_print; ?></textarea>

        <label>Quick Description:</label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="quick_description"><?php echo $quick_description; ?></textarea>
        <?php
    }

    add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

    function save_details(){
        global $post;

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "discount", $_POST["discount"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "market_value", $_POST["market_value"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "start_date", $_POST["start_date"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "end_date", $_POST["end_date"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "highlights", $_POST["highlights"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "fine_print", $_POST["fine_print"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "quick_description", $_POST["quick_description"]);
    }
```

However when i go to the Add Deal it doesn't show any of these, confused.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
Dave

Var dump :

```
array(2) {
  ["deal"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["side"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["core"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["submitdiv"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(9) "submitdiv"
          ["title"]=>
          string(7) "Publish"
          ["callback"]=>
          string(20) "post_submit_meta_box"
          ["args"]=>
          NULL
        }
        ["Citiesdiv"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(9) "Citiesdiv"
          ["title"]=>
          string(6) "Cities"
          ["callback"]=>
          string(24) "post_categories_meta_box"
          ["args"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["taxonomy"]=>
            string(6) "Cities"
          }
        }
      }
      ["low"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["postimagediv"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(12) "postimagediv"
          ["title"]=>
          string(14) "Featured Image"
          ["callback"]=>
          string(23) "post_thumbnail_meta_box"
          ["args"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
    }
    ["normal"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["core"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["slugdiv"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(7) "slugdiv"
          ["title"]=>
          string(4) "Slug"
          ["callback"]=>
          string(18) "post_slug_meta_box"
          ["args"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["post"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["side"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["low"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["deal-meta"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(9) "deal-meta"
          ["title"]=>
          string(12) "Deal Options"
          ["callback"]=>
          string(12) "deal_options"
          ["args"]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "my_add_meta_boxes");
function my_add_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box("deal-meta", "Deal Options", "deal_options", "deal", "side", "low");
}
```

Let me know if that works.

----EDIT----

Try adding the following as a plugin in your plugins directory.  Disable your plugin, enable the test plugin, and add a post.  The metabox should be at the bottom of the post edit screen.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Metabox Test
*/

add_action("plugins_loaded", "metaboxtest_action_plugins_loaded");

function metaboxtest_action_plugins_loaded(){
    add_action("add_meta_boxes", "metaboxtest_action_add_meta_boxes");
}

function metaboxtest_action_add_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box("metabox-test", 
        "Testing", 
        "metaboxtest_metabox_output", 
        "post");
}

function metaboxtest_metabox_output(){
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Thanks chris for your reply unfortunately still shows nothing,:)

Comment: Click "Screen Options" (should be in the upper right of the edit screen.) Is there a checkbox for "Deal Options"?

Comment: No chris checked here aswell  :)

Comment: Wow. (1) Try adding it to the post editor? Change the fourth parameter in `add_meta_box` from "deal" to "post".  (2) Simplify `deal_options()` to just `echo "Hello World"`

Comment: changed to deal -> post and the function deal_options() to just echo "Hello World". Still Nothing on Add Deal page. :(

Comment: Is my_add_meta_boxes being called? Put `die("yes, it is");` in the function.

Comment: when i do this i dont get any wp page just a blank page saying yes it is :)

Comment: That's a good sign.  Delete the die() statement and add `global $wp_meta_boxes; echo "<pre>"; var_dump($wp_meta_boxes); die();` after the `add_meta_box()` call.

Comment: posted the var dump in main question :)

Comment: ok, change "post" to "deal" in `add_meta_box` in the test plugin, and see if it works on the "deal" edit screen.

Comment: Thanks Chris for all your help, much appreciated thats it working now :) Btw is there away to convert one of the inputs to a date and time field ?